# Difference between Logic Test and Application Test in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, unit-testing

In Xcode when you create a new objective c unit test case, it asks you to choose between "Logic" test and "Application" test. What's the difference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Logic Test part is for doing [White Box testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White-box_testing); it allows you to test things at a more granular level.

Application Test is more like [Black Box testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing) where you check that interactions with UI controls and the UI of your application is giving you the expected results/behavior.

Comment: For a CLI application, would you always pick "Logic Test?"

Comment: I have not worked with CLI applications but the obvious answer looks yes as we  do not have user interaction.

Answer (score 5):

Logic tests are the very low unit test type tests. (Think a single method.)

Application tests are at a higher level and include the whole of the app, the object graph, outlets, etc. (Think more of an integration test.)

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/135-Unit_Testing_Applications/unit_testing_applications.html

Comment: Do both types apply to CLI applications?