# Difference between application test and logic test code template in XCode 4.2

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, uikit, ocunit

What's the difference between selecting *Test Type Application* or *Logic* in XCode 4.2, when creating a new *Objective-C test case class* from the code template?

I know the **conceptual** difference between application and logic tests (answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884204/difference-between-logic-test-and-application-test-in-xcode)). My question is if XCode does something different for each test type or if the difference is purely artificial **at class level**.

Besides using different code templates, the only actual difference that I can see is that by default application tests `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` and logic tests don't. However, I've written logic tests that use `UIKit` and in most cases it works (with the exception of using monsters like `UIWebView` and such).

Answer (score 1):

At least it sets a bundle loader and test host which is your application and injects the tests in there, allowing you to run your tests within the context of your application, which in turn allows you to test basically all layers of it, including views for example and other components that are part of UIKit. I **think** that logic tests only allows you to test foundation objects.

Of you search for "bundle loader" and "test host" in the configuration for both a logic test target and an application test target  you can see that the values are different.

Comment: I think you're talking about the target. I'm talking about a new test class.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I think the only difference there is the class template where just as you say it imports UIKit and it also put some template code there that wouldn't work in a logic test class. I've always just removed it and started over myself, but from what I've seen I don't think there is any other difference than that.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between Xcode's application and logic tests is the type of unit test Xcode adds to the unit test class's implementation file. You can read a more detailed explanation in the following article:

[Xcode 4.2: Application and Logic Unit Test Classes](http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/11/xcode-4-2-application-and-logic-unit-test-classes/)

Comment: This answer is vague and does not address the OP's question. Literally half of your answer is a link to the documentation which the OP has clearly read based on the contents of the question.